# Add custom field for skype

Tags: wordpress

For my website I use Advance Custom Field for Wordpress and now i'd like to create a custom field for skype call.

I create a custom field text for "skype" and I add this on my single.php

```
<?php if ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'skype', true ) ) : ?> 
        <p><span class="list">
            <?php _e( 'Skype: '); ?>
            </span>
        <?php the_field('skype'); ?>
</p><?php endif; ?>
```

I try to add this

```
<a href="skype: yourskypeid?call">
          <img src="http://cdn.dev.skype.com/uri/callbutton_32px.png"
       alt="Skype Me™!" style="border: none;margin: 32px; vertical-align: -41px">
 </a><br />
  <a href="http://www.skype.com/go/download">Get Skype</a> and call me for free.<br />
```

to have a skype button to call but it doesn't work.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.skypeassets.com/i/scom/js/skype-uri.js"></script>
<div id="SkypeButton_Call_prince_1">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    Skype.ui({
      "name": "call",
      "element": "SkypeButton_Call_YOURSKYPENAME_1",
      "participants": ["YOURSKYPENAME"],
      "imageSize": 32
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

**For more See here [Skype Call Button](http://www.skype.com/en/features/skype-buttons/create-skype-buttons/)**

also this should work..

```
<a href="skype:yourskypeid?call">Call Yourskypeid</a>
```